Hashed cross-product transformation in PyTorch
I want to implement a hashed cross product transformation like the one Keras uses:
>>> layer = keras.layers.HashedCrossing(num_bins=5, output_mode='one_hot')
>>> feat1 = np.array([1, 5, 2, 1, 4])
>>> feat2 = np.array([2, 9, 42, 37, 8])
>>> layer((feat1, feat2))
<tf.Tensor: shape=(5, 5), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)>
>>> layer2 = keras.layers.HashedCrossing(num_bins=5, output_mode='int')
>>> layer2((feat1, feat2))
<tf.Tensor: shape=(5,), dtype=int64, numpy=array([2, 0, 4, 0, 2])>


This layer performs crosses of categorical features using the "hashing trick". Conceptually, the transformation can be thought of as: hash(concatenate(features)) % num_bins.

I'm struggling to understand the concatenate(features) part. Do I have to do the hash of each "pair" of features?
In the meantime, I tried with this:
>>> cross_product_idx = (feat1*feat2.max()+1 + feat2) % num_bins
>>> cross_product = nn.functional.one_hot(cross_product_idx, num_bins)

It works, but not using a hash function can cause problems with distributions

I could trace it to this part of the code where they simply use "X" as a string separator on one set of crossed values from various features.

I'm struggling to understand the concatenate(features) part. Do I have to do the hash of each "pair" of features?

If you are crossing two features, for each pair of values from each feature, you would need to "combine" them somehow (which is what they term as "concatenation"). The concatenation I see from the code is just string concatenation using the separator "X".
So if you have feature A: "A1", "A2" and feature B: "B1", "B2", "B3", you would need to do

hash("A1_X_B1") % num_bins
hash("A1_X_B2") % num_bins
hash("A1_X_B3") % num_bins
hash("A2_X_B1") % num_bins
hash("A2_X_B2") % num_bins
hash("A2_X_B2") % num_bins

and then one-hot encode these numbers if you want.
Tensoring the operations
I'm going to assume your features are categorical but numeric IDs, because if they were strings you would need to additionally map them out to integers.
PRIME_NUM = 2_147_483_647

def feature_cross(feature_a: torch.Tensor, feature_b: torch.Tensor, num_bins: int) -> torch.Tensor:
    device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    feature_a = feature_a.to(device)
    feature_b = feature_b.to(device)
    
    # Add an additional dimension and repeat the feature to match the other feature's size
    a_expanded = feature_a.unsqueeze(1).expand(-1, feature_b.size(0))
    # Add an additional dimension and repeat the feature to match the other feature's size
    b_expanded = feature_b.unsqueeze(0).expand(feature_a.size(0), -1)
    
    combined = (a_expanded.long() * PRIME_NUM + b_expanded.long())
    
    hashed = combined % num_bins
    
    return hashed

feature_a = torch.tensor([1001, 1002, 1003, 1004], dtype=torch.long)
feature_b = torch.tensor([2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005], dtype=torch.long)
num_bins = 1000

result = feature_cross(feature_a, feature_b, num_bins)
print(result)

To take an example, if A = [1,2,3] and B = [4,5], we are expanding them to
# a_expanded

1 1
2 2
3 3

# b_expanded

4 5
4 5
4 5


and combining them through addition (with prime number multiplication) to achieve a cross.
You're right that using tuples can also be an option for combining the values since tuples can be hashed, but I don't know of a tensorised way of creating tuples.

And how can I do the hash of each item in a tensor? Is there a "pytorch way?" (parallelized, efficient, and possibly on GPU). As tuple is also hashable, instead of converting it to string, perhaps I could hash((f1,f2))

Edited the answer with a more "tensorised" approach.

Btw, when you do combined = ... % prime do you mean combined = ... % PRIME_NUM? This looks great, thank you!

@DavidDavó yes, but actually that final% is not required because we immediately do % num_bins after that. No problem, please consider marking it as "accepted" if it solved your question.
